# Assign ListBox or CheckBox Selection to Module

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I am freshly new to userforms and trying to further streamline an already VB "automated" process through a selection of possible reports I validate on a report-to-report cadence.

The process includes pulling reports from two separate folders, the old reports and the new reports, then validating them per report (by-country). I have this process down in VB script, but I have to constantly change the dates according to the "last pull date" and "new pull date", the countries affected, and the project I am working within.

The idea would be to type in the dates, check off what project I am working on, and then check the countries I will be working within. Below I have outlined the steps to complete.

1. Select Project (Only a single selection allowed)
2. Select Country Report (Multi-Selection)
3. Type last pull date to navigate to last pull directory folder format.("yyyy-mm-dd")
4. Type new pull date to navigate to new pull directory folder format.("yyyy-mm-dd")

Example:

Projects-- in single selected listbox
A , B , C (I choose B)

Countries -- can be a multi-selection listbox or can be checkboxes
AR, BR, CA, SA, WD (I choose BR, CA, & WD)

Last Pull Date -- typed in
2019-06-23

New Pull Date -- typed in 
2019-11-07

--> Question: How do you assign the variables selected in steps 1-4 to be entered dynamically into a subprocess? The list i believe i can get down, but how do I assign the check list to a variant and then to a variable within a subprocess to be executed?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon this does not explicitly answer my question, but thank you.

Comment: I don't know what your question is, there's 5 of them here, and no code whatsoever. Feel free to [edit] your post to clarify what you're trying to do, what you've tried to do it, and how it's failing. The answer to "Is X possible?" is almost always "Yes".

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Apologies, I tried to narrow down the question in the edit. I want to know how to assign the checkbox click as a variable to activate a subprocess. This may be easier to accomplish by using a multi-selection list instead.